# Leaderboard section missing in Game Center in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

I'm trying to configure game center for my app, leaderboards and multiplayer later. But my app store connect page looks different than on screenshots from docs. I don't have *Leaderboards* section, and in *Multiplayer Compatibility* i have no plus button. How to fix this?

**My app store connect page:**
[image]
**From Docs:**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set it up done yet. Select `Game Center` on `Services` section.

[image]

Scroll down to `Leaderboard` then `+` to add a new board. Following a few steps to add name, id, format, sort order, etc.

[image]

About `Multiplayer Compatibility`. Since you've not published any builds/other apps, you couldn't see it. It will enable for earlier compatible versions or even other apps within the same team ID.